# How do i limit this match to one character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a regular expression

```
(?<=\w)([A-Z]|_|\s)
```

That matches against the following correctly

```
ModelName  (matches N)
modelName  (matches N)
Model Name (matches space)
model name (matches space)
model_name (matches underscore)
```

but the following is incorrect

```
Model_Name (matches underscore and N)
```

In the latter, I need to only match the space, but have the same regexp matches on all the previous results.

I'm a little rusty, so does anyone know how to best achieve this?

My context is as follows:

```
/**
 * Converts 'ModelName', 'modelName' and 'model_name' to 'model-name'
 * @param  string $word
 * @return string
 */
public static function hyphenate($word)
{
    return strtolower(str_replace([' ', '_'], '', preg_replace('!(?<=\\w)([A-Z]|_|\\s)!', '-$1', $word)));
}
```

The last failing match will make this function return `model--name`.

Would it be easier to just do another str_replace('--', '', $word) before returning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do it all in one step you can use

```
preg_replace('/(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?:([A-Z])|[_\h])/', '-\1', $string);
```

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/rT0kC8).

The idea is to capture the uppercase letter in first capturing group, which will then be empty if you match a `_` or `\h` (horizontal whitespace).

Your issue was that `\w` stands for `[a-zA-Z_]`, so the look behind matched `_` as well.

Comment: I was looking at this from the wrong angle. Thanks! PS, I always wondered how passive groups worked too, this is a great example for me. Thanks very much.